# Cardboard app for Android: Gaze Input Module trigger problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm building an app with Unity and Google Cardboard SDK.

First prototype involves looking at items coming from the distance towards the user.
The user taps (pulls the trigger on the Cardboard device) and when the `Gaze Input Module`'s cursor is on an item coming towards the user, it's removed.
The problem is, that on Android devices a tap on one item works as it should, but also the **next** item that's coming towards the user is getting hit as though it was tapped even though I'm only gazing at it without pulling the trigger.

I've tried using different Event Triggers on the oncoming prefabs but that doesn't make a difference.
Switching the `Tap is Trigger` checkbox on the Cardboard object sort of reverses the problem: then I have to tap every item twice for it to register a hit (instead of hitting two items with one tap). Also quite annoying.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? I use Unity 5.2.3p1 and Cardboard SDK 0.5.2, both of which are the latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/issues/122) on Google-Cardboard-Unity's Github page and it seems to be a bug that occurs on pre-4.4 Android versions. They don't mention a fix however.